# Homotopy and Semidirect Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I know there is a relation in homotopy theory which is $\pi(G\times H) = \pi(G)\times\pi(H)$. However, does this relation still hold for $\pi_0$ which may not be a group? Moreover, is there such a relation for the semi-direct product, e.g., $\pi(G\rtimes H) = \pi(G) \rtimes \pi(H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it holds $\pi_0(X\times Y)\cong \pi_0(X)\times \pi_0(Y).$

Concerning your second question:

The homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)$ are defined for **topological spaces** (with base points) $X$, so they do not depend on the group structure, if $X$ is a topological group. Since semidirect products of topological groups have the direct product as underlying space, it holds $$\pi_i(G\rtimes H)=\pi_i(G\times H)\cong \pi_i(G)\times \pi_i(H).$$

Comment: A minor correction to the answer: the homotopy groups are defined for **topological spaces with base point**; I think trouble can arise if the distinction is not kept. Pursuing  this distinction allows one to think of spaces with many base point, and also spaces with other kinds of structure appropriate to the geometry, such as filtered spaces, and $n$-cubes of spaces, and their appropriate invariants.

Comment: I think this has solve my problem (even I still need a bit more reading to fully understand it). But I notice that you stress that "if $X$ is a topological group", is this a necessary condition for the relation you have wrote in your answer? If I have a topological space which is not a group, is there such a neat relation? E.g, $\pi(\frac{G_1 \times G_2}{G_3 \times G_4})$, where $G_i$s are groups, but their quotient may not be a group.